# Upload the file (image) on Nodejs server using mongoose, with its original name

Tags: express, mongoose, multer

I am uploading an image file using nodeJS and express and currently, image is saved with a random file name with no specific file type. I want to save the file name with an extension so that I could display it as well, because currently in DB file name is saved as the original file but in the upload folder, it assigns a random name (string) and when I fetch that back I have no clue how to display it as it does not have any file type/extension,i.e. .png/JPEG.

```
//Schema

const AddProductSchema = new Schema({

  productCode: String,
  productTitle: String,
  productImage: String

//defined express, mongoose, multer and upload const for the directory
const upload = multer({
  dest: __dirname + '/uploads/images'
});

//post method
app.post("/addProductToDB", upload.single("productImage"), function(req, res) {

// to get the detail filled on add product form
  const addproduct = new AddProduct({
    productCode: req.body.productCode,
    productTitle: req.body.productTitle,
    productImage: req.file.originalname

  });

  addproduct.save();
  res.redirect("/products");

});
```

Comment: Manage to sort this using fs.rename. I saved the file with its filename and then used fs.rename to replace it with the original name. //  fs.rename(
    __dirname + '/uploads/images/'+req.file.filename,
    __dirname + '/uploads/images/'+req.file.originalname,
    (err)=>{
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }else{
    console.log("Rename complete");
  }

Answer (score 0):

You should save productImage with buffer type if you want to display image  `productImage: Buffer` 
There's a package called sharp which can help you customize image file before save to database called sharp https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp 
If you want to have png file type before saving, you can use the following code

```
  const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer)
      .png()
      .toBuffer();
```

Then you just need to save buffer to your `productImage: buffer`